# How to bypass breaking of loop in GAP

Tags: gap

I was trying to find whether there exists a finite  group with the following presentation:

$$<a, b,c, d|\,a^2, b^2,c^2, d^2, (a\,c)^{4\,i}, (a\,d)^{3\,j}, (b\,c)^{3\,k}, (b\,c)^{3\,l}, (a\,c\,d)^{3\,m}, (b\,c\,d)^{4\,n},(a\,b\,c)^{3\,o},(a\,b\,d)^{4\,p},(a\,b\,c\,d)^{3\,q}>,$$
 where $$1\le i,j,\ldots,q \le 3$$ are integers.

I wrote a code. (I'll give it at the end). While running, it gives the error messages as follows:

> ### Error Message
>
> I  Coset table calculation failed -- trying with bigger table limit
>
> I  Coset table calculation failed -- trying with bigger table limit
>
> I  Coset table calculation failed -- trying with bigger table limit
>
> I  Coset table calculation failed -- trying with bigger table limit
>
> Error, exceeded the permitted memory (`-o' command line option) in
>
> prev[2 * limit] := 2 * limit - 1; called from
>
> TCENUM.CosetTableFromGensAndRels( fgens, grels, fsgens ) called from
>
> CosetTableFromGensAndRels( fgens, grels, List( trial, UnderlyingElement )
>
> ) called from Attempt( gens ) called from
>
> FinIndexCyclicSubgroupGenerator( G, infinity ) called from
>
> (  )  called from read-eval loop at line 7 of >second.g you can 'return;'

If we now give the command **"brk> return;"** then GAP terminates after giving a message

> gap: cannot extend the workspace any more!

I was looking for a solution for this problem. **I don't want termination of the program.** Otherwise I have to do $3^9=19683$ runnings vy hand and its a dam boring job.

> ### Code
>
> for i in [1 .. 3] do
>
> for j in [1 .. 3] do
>
> for k in [1 .. 3] do
>
> for l in [1 .. 3] do
>
> for m in [1 .. 3] do
>
> for n in [1 .. 3] do
>
> for o in [1 .. 3] do
>
> for p in [1 .. 3] do
>
> for q in [1 .. 3] do
>
> F2 := FreeGroup( "a", "b","c", "d" );
>
> A5 := F2 / [ F2.1^2, F2.2^2,F2.3^2, F2.4^2, (F2.1*F2.3)^(4*i), (F2.1*F2.4)^(3*j), (F2.2*F2.3)^(3*k), (F2.2*F2.3)^(3*l), (F2.1*F2.3*F2.4)^(3*m), (F2.2*F2.3*F2.4)^(4*n),(F2.1*F2.2*F2.3)^(3*o),(F2.1*F2.2*F2.4)^(4*p),(F2.1*F2.2*F2.3*F2.4)^(3*q) ];
>
> AppendTo( "second.txt",[i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,],Size(A5),"\n" );
>
> od; od; od; od; od; od; od; od; od;

Comment: Why do you increment q, p etc manually -- the for loop already does that for you...

Comment: You mean "i:=i+1; " commands?

Comment: Exactly. A `for` loop already increments the counters for you, that's what makes it a `for` loop :-)

Comment: Thanks. I made changes according to your suggestion. Now I'll check your answer.

Comment: To format the code, please indent it with four spaces - see e.g. how this is done in @Max's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `silent` option to achieve that. Unfortunately, using it in this example
is a bit tricky (we cannot directly pass it to the `Size` command, which triggers the
coset enumeration, because `Size` cannot deal with failure of the enumeration).

But this should work. Of course it will only find examples which are small enough
for the naive coset enumeration to work, so you may easily miss finite examples.
To do this properly, I am afraid you will have to learn more of the theoretical
background, and also perhaps look at tools like ACE, the advanced coset enumerator.
But even then it is a slow business.

One other thing you could do is to set the `max` option to a larger numerical value than
the default value `CosetTableDefaultMaxLimit`; you then need more time and more,
though.

```
F := FreeGroup( "a", "b", "c", "d" );
for i in [1 .. 3] do for j in [1 .. 3] do
 for k in [1 .. 3] do for l in [1 .. 3] do
  for m in [1 .. 3] do for n in [1 .. 3] do
   for o in [1 .. 3] do for p in [1 .. 3] do
    for q in [1 .. 3] do
      Print("Running computation for ",[i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,],"\n");
      rels := [ F.1^2, F.2^2,F.3^2, F.4^2,
                (F.1*F.3)^(4*i), (F.1*F.4)^(3*j), (F.2*F.3)^(3*k),
                (F.2*F.3)^(3*l), (F.1*F.3*F.4)^(3*m), (F.2*F.3*F.4)^(4*n),
                (F.1*F.2*F.3)^(3*o), (F.1*F.2*F.4)^(4*p),
                (F.1*F.2*F.3*F.4)^(3*q) ];
      G := F / rels;

      G := FactorGroupFpGroupByRels(F, rels : silent);
      ct := TryCosetTableInWholeGroup(TrivialSubgroup(G) : silent);
      if ct <> fail then
        size := Length(ct[1]);
        #AppendTo( "second.txt",[i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,],size,"\n" );
        Print( "  found G for ",[i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,]," of size ", size,"\n" );
      fi;
    od;
   od; od;
  od; od;
 od; od;
od; od;
```